# Using AJAX live search to craw internal web pages

Tags: php, ajax, xml, livesearch

I am using W3S's Ajax live search tutorial code for my search box. I've setted few links in xml file, becase this search box should be used for conneting the relative internal pages. It works fine, but the problem is the searching result shows up in the other mysterious page, I have to click it to link the page I want to go, which wasn't what I expect.

It is my first time to try php, Ajax, xml, etc... I've searched the similar questions and answers, but didn't find any.

------This is livesearch.php code, basically it is the same from W3S---

```
<?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("links.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');


$q=$_GET["s"];


if (strlen($q)>0)
{
$hint="";
for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++)
{
$y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
$z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1)
{
if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q))
{
if ($hint=="")
{
$hint="<a href='" . 
$z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
"' target='_blank'>" . 
$y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
}
else
{
$hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" . 
$z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
"' target='_blank'>" . 
$y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
}
}
}
}
}


if ($hint=="")
{
$response="no suggestion";
}
else
{
$response=$hint;
}



echo $response;
?>
```

-------script code is on my index.html page --------

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showResult(str)
{
  if (str.length==0)
  { 
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// IE6, IE5 
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

----- this is the code I am using for XML -----

```
<pages>
<link>
<title>Name 1</title>
<url>http://www.xxxx1.html</url>
</link>
<link>
<title> Name 2</title>
<url>http://www.xxxx2.html</url>
</link>
<link>
<title>Name 3</title>
<url>
http://www.xxxx3.html
</url>
</link>
</pages>
```

----- this is the code I am using for search box -----

```
                  <input id="livesearch" autocomplete="on" ibMouseDown="" onBlur="" autopcapitalize="none" autofocus name="s" value="" placeholder="Search for wines or winerary" required="required" type="search" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">
                     <button class="rd__button" data-trach-action="hero" hata-track-label="searchicon" id="search-action" title="Search">
                       <i class="search-icon rd__svg-icon rd__svg-icon--textsecondary rd__svg-icon--large">
                       </i>
                     </button>
                </div>
               </form>
```

----- I've also added autocomplete in my index.html ------

```
<script>
    var name = ["", "", ""];

   $('#livesearch').autocomplete({
     source: name
   },{});

   </script>
```

I think the problem I have now, it maybe some part of code are not written, that is why the webpage didn't show up directly, just I have no clue how shall I do further. Please if you know something, let me know, any advise are welcome.

Comment: What do you even mean by "the searching result shows up in the other mysterious page"?  Also, I see no AJAX, PHP, or XML in the code you're showing.  All I'm seeing is a jQuery auto-complete where the data source is an array of three empty strings.  And a reference to a function called `showResult` which isn't defined anywhere.  You've linked to examples you're using, but where is *your* code and what specifically isn't working in *your* code?  It's really not clear to me what specifically you're asking.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I was also confuse how to paste other code here, I though maybe the code was too long, so this website didn't allow me to paste it. But now I know why I couldn't paste it. Anyway, as you can see, this code is copied from W3S tutorial, I don't know how does "showResult" work .... I am not sure how to define it, sorry for this stupid answer, but I am still learning  but really bad in jquery and php this kind of code.

Comment: "the searching result shows up in the other mysterious page" --- I think because the code I wrote, it leads me to my livesearch.php page, and I have to click the search result to go to the webpage I searched. But my problem is I want to jump to the result page directly, so I can skip livesearch.php. How can I make it happens?